# Why and How does different depths of water affect the wavelength of a wave on such medium?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, water, wavelength

When a water wave passes through from a deep water to shallow water , refraction is said to occur due to it's decrease in wavelength and thus decrease in speed , based on the formula v=fλ. Question is , why should wavelength decrease in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The relation between the angular frequency $\omega=2\pi f$ and wavenumber $k=2\pi /\lambda$ for waves on shallow water is 
$$
\omega = k \sqrt{gh},
$$
where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $h$ the water depth. Since the frequency cannot change, a reduction in depth leads to an increase in $k$ and hence a shorter wavelength.  To derive the $\omega(k)$ relation you need to set up and solve the  equations of motion for the fluid. I don't know any easy short cut to this. Water waves are not simple things.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$
v = f \lambda$$

provides a relation between three quantities. That is all. It is not that a decrease of wavelength "in the first place" causes a change in propagation velocity.

The form of such expressions does not say anything about causation. One can rewrite it as

$$\lambda = \frac{v}{f}.$$

The propagation velocity of the waves is a property of the medium. In this case, it depends on the depth of the water.